# Dynamic Regex for extracting dot notion based variables

Tags: javascript, regex

What Regex would I use to return all strings (in dot notation) that contain `scope.`, but return full values including any number of dots that follow.

For example, the code below does not return the `".string"` part.

`> "scope.object.string".match(/(scope[.]\w+)/gi)`

`< ["scope.object"]`

The code below will return `"scope.object.object2"` because I explicitly added a second `[.]\w+`, which is not dynamic.

```
> "scope.object.object2.string".match(/(scope[.]\w+[.]\w+)/gi)
```

`< ["scope.object.object2"]`

How would I do this dynamically so that I could get this value returned from this string:

`> "scope.object.string    scope.object.object2.string    scope.object.object2.object3.string".match(/newRegex/)`

`< ["scope.object.string", "scope.object.object2.string", "scope.object.object2.object3.string"]`

Even better if you can remove the `"scope."` part from each string with the same regex in the same call:

`> "scope.object.string    scope.object.object2.string    scope.object.object2.object3.string".match(/newRegex/)`

`< ["object.string", "object.object2.string", "object.object2.object3.string"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scope[.](?:\w+[.])*\w+
```

You can use this.If you want to remove`scope.` the use

```
scope[.]((?:\w+[.])*\w+)
```

And grab the group 1 .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/24

```
var re = /scope[.]((?:\w+[.])*\w+)/gm;
var str = 'scope.object.object2.string\nscope.object.object2';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: `"scope.object.string    scope.object.object2.string    scope.object.object2.object3.string".match(/scope[.]((?:\w+[.])*\w+)/gm)` doesn't remove the `scope.` part, perhaps I'm doing it wrong. But its good enough, thanks!

Comment: I can't figure out how to do this. As it returns an array, selecting `[1]` in that array only returns the second item (of the array, unrelated to `match`). I think I know how I would do this if it wasn't an array, is that what you mean?